# auto calculate table row having data from mysql using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

hi guys I have a code here that collects data from mysql and display it in html table here's the php code:

```
<?Php
include("database_connection.php");
$query="select money
        from `money_denomination_t`
        ";
        $select_data_Result = mysqli_query($objconn, $query);
?>
```

and here's HTMl code:

```
<table id="">
<thead>
<th>Money</th><th>x</th><th>Amount</th><th>=</th><th>Total</th>
<thead>
<?php 
$id = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_data_Result))
{
    $id++;
?>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="money[]" value="<?php echo $row['money']; ?>" ></td>
<td>x</td>
<td><input type='text' name="amount[]"></td>
<td>=</td>
<td><input type='text' name="rowtotal[]"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php
}   
?>
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type='text' name="total"></td>
</table>
```

What I wanted to do is to get the product of money and amount and display it in rowtotal using keyup javascript anyone who can help me achieve it

I already have here the code that sum up all the values of rowtotal and display it in textbox total and its already fine I just need help about computing each rows to integrate here:

```
<script>
var totalperrow = document.getElementsByName("rowtotal[]");
var totalperrow_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(totalperrow);


for(var i=0; i < totalperrow_array.length; i++){
    totalperrow_array[i].addEventListener("keyup", sum_values);
}
function sum_values(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < totalperrow_array.length; i++){
        sum += parseFloat(totalperrow_array[i].value);
    }
    if(!isNaN(sum))
    {
        document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = sum;
        alert(sum);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I interpreted the question correctly - the following code uses a `for` loop to emulate the recordset iteration and generates random amounts of money for each row. The javascript finds all the `amount` fields and listens for `keyup` events on those fields. The `keyup` event triggers the calculation of that row's total which also updates the grand total at the bottom of the table. Incidentally your original HTML is invalid - the last few `td` elements MUST be within a table row!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>keyup sum</title>
        <style>
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;}
            input[type='text']{padding:0.5rem;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table id="">
            <thead>
                <th>Money</th>
                <th>x</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>=</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            <thead>
        <?php

        $id = 0;
        for( $i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ){

            $id++;

            $row['money']=mt_rand(5,250);

        ?>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="money[]" value="<?php echo $row['money']; ?>" >
                    </td>
                    <td>x</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="amount[]">
                    </td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name="rowtotal[]">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php
        }   
        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=4 align='right'>Grand Total</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name="total"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <script>

            let total=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="total"]');



            const calculatetotal=function(){
                let sum=0;
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="text"][name="rowtotal[]"]' ) ).forEach( field=>{
                    if( !isNaN( parseFloat( field.value ) ) )sum += parseFloat( field.value );
                });
                return sum;
            }



            Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="text"][name="amount[]"]' ) ).forEach( input=>{
                input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
                    if( !isNaN( this.value ) ){
                        let money = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="money[]"]')
                        let result = this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="rowtotal[]"]')
                        let product = this.value * money.value;

                        result.value=product;
                        total.value=calculatetotal();
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

To calculate the row total the above code references the active input's parent (table) row as the base when searching for the other text fields in that row. Using `querySelector` you can be very specific for what you search for - a very useful reference [can be found here](http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf)

Comment: hi sir @RamRaider thank you for your quick response and you even modified my code but my concern now is how and where can I insert the statement `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_data_Result))`  to display and assign the value of money in the first column of the table. thank you in advance

Comment: simply change the `for( $i=0...){` for `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select_data_Result)){`

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understood your question. I have done the same project before for a billing software. here is my js code to get the total. I hope it may help you.
This is html code:

```
    <input  type="text" name="Total[]" onkeyup="total()"  id="Total" readonly/>
    <input type="text" name="Grandtotal[]" id="GrandTotal"/>
```

This is jacascript code:

```
 <script>
   function total() {
          var inputs = document.getElementsByName('Total'),
              result = document.getElementById('GrandTotal'),
              sum = 0;            
          for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
              var ip = inputs[i];
              if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("GrandTotal") < 0) {
                  sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
              }
          }
          result.value = sum;
         }
</script>
```